# How to add a UIView which is created in storyboard as a pop-up in Swift?

Tags: iphone, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, ios-app-group

I did the following:
1. Dragged UIView to place it in the ViewController ribbon
[image: Dragged UIView to place it in the ViewController ribbon]

2. Created a custom UIView class and added the outlets to the '*Edit Profile View*' view fields:

import UIKit

class EditProfileView: UIView {

```
let globalDataHandler = GlobalDataHandler.sharedInstance

@IBOutlet weak var firstNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var userNameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func saveEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}
@IBAction func cancelEditButton(sender: AnyObject) {
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/
```

}

3. Gave '*EditProfileView*' class as the Custom Class for the '*Edit Profile View*' view in *Storyboard*.
4. Created an object for '*EditProfileView*' class in *ProfileViewController* and added the '*Edit Profile View*' view to the main view upon clicking edit button in *ProfileViewController*.

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController {

```
let profileView = EditProfileView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func editProfileButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    profileView.firstNameTextField.text = "First Name"
    profileView.lastNameTextField.text = "Last Name"
    profileView.userNameTextField.text = "User Name"
    profileView.emailTextField.text = "Email"
    let testFrame : CGRect = CGRectMake(50,100,300,300)
    profileView.frame = testFrame
    self.view.addSubview(profileView)
}
```

}

But, the '*Edit Profile View*' view doesn't appear on ProfileViewController.
Please help.

Comment: Why don't you just make `profileView` and IBOutlet of the view you dragged into the storyboard by selecting "Edit Profile View" in the document outline and control dragging into your `ProfileViewController`? Initializing it in code like `EditProfileView()` will not have the desired effect because there's overridden initializer that setups up your subviews.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link your UIView and your View (should be a distinct UIViewController) in the Xib.

```
profileView = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ProfileViewController")
```

You must have an UIPresentationController for your ProfileVC

```
class ProfilePresentationController : UIPresentationController {
    override func frameOfPresentedViewInContainerView() -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: (presentingViewController.view.frame.width / 2.0) - 150.0, y: (presentingViewController.view.frame.height / 2.0) - 100.0, width: 300.0, height: 200.0)
    }
}
```

Your EditProfileView must implement the following delegate:

```
UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate
```

the following properties of your profileView must also be set to:

```
profileView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom
profileView.transitioningDelegate = self
```

After that you can implement the delegate required method

```
func presentationControllerForPresentedViewController(presented: UIViewController, presentingViewController presenting: UIViewController, sourceViewController source: UIViewController) -> UIPresentationController? {
        return ProfilePresentationController(presentedViewController: presented, presentingViewController: presenting)
}
```